# What differentiates a "Game Design/Development" question from a question that belongs on this site?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, faq

Game design and development questions are considered off-topic, and should be asked on the corresponding [Stack Exchange sister site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). But what defines a question as being about game development? How do I know where to ask my questions about consoles and mechanics?

Answer (score 2):

Stealing a leaf from the discussions about FAQs on the [Game Deve](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/what-should-our-faq-contain)[lopment site](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow/14#14) to start this off, these topics are very explicitly about Game Development and should definitely be asked over on the other site.

- Game design (architecture, gameplay, ideas, mechanics, etc)
- Game assets (creation, storage, editing, etc)<sup>†</sup>
- Game programming (coding, bugs, best practices, patterns, etc)
- Game development (testing, team development, tools, etc)
- Game release (hosting, publishing, etc)
- Game industry (careers, trends, technology, etc)

<sup>†</sup> *Note- This is refers to assets in the game's architecture, not things like "Where are replays stored for StarCraft 2?" or "Where do I put music files to support NS Shaft?"*

Comment: I've got some additional words to add, but it'll take me some time to compose them. In the mean time, feel free to add to this post, or add your own answers!