# Are questions on why 2 quite similar gaming companies handle a particular aspect very differently on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want to ask why Sony and Nintendo handle indie games and community building so differently even though they're both Japanese multinationals. Would this question be on-topic or be made on-topic?

Answer (score 8):

I think such question will fall under this off topic category:

> Questions about Game Design and Development are off topic. This includes speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to both mechanics and narrative. You might want to ask over at GameDev.SE, but be sure to read their FAQ

Answer (score 5):

In addition to arghtype's answer, I've pulled up the official [Arqade FAQ page](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/792/250180) for what types of questions should fall under the game development reason.

> - Game design (architecture, gameplay, ideas, mechanics, etc)
> - Game assets (creation, storage, editing, etc)†
> - Game programming (coding, bugs, best practices, patterns, etc)
> - Game development (testing, team development, tools, etc)
> - Game release (hosting, publishing, etc)
> - Game industry (careers, trends, technology, etc)

Your proposed question falls under "Game Industry" in that post, and is better suited for GameDev.SE.